# Converting a suspended Google+ profile to a Page, without affecting YouTube name?

Tags: youtube, google-plus

A year ago I created [this YouTube user](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAMxo52Bz5B-S7cXINrum9w) called `CmisSync CMIS Synchronizer` and uploaded some video tutorials about my product called "CmisSync".

Somehow I also got [an associated Google+ account](https://plus.google.com/u/0/101022579591486022160) with the same name `CmisSync CMIS Synchronizer`.

Unfortunately, the Google+ account recently got disabled:

[image]

Apparently I should have created a Google+ Page instead, as product names are not accepted as Google+ profile names.
Fair enough, my bad, then let's destroy my profile and create a Page instead, I thought.
So I click `Take action`, a popup appears:

---

[image]

---

Looks good, what I want is `Create a Google+ Page`, so I click on it and get:

---

[image]

---

**PROBLEM**:

In the screenshot above I am told that I need to provide a person name, and this name will be used for all associated products, including YouTube as explained by the [Learn more](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=112783&hl=en&authuser=0) link.

I don't want the YouTube user to have the name of a real person, as it is about a product.

**QUESTION**:

- Should I give my real name in the dialog above, then I will be able to change the YouTube-visible name back to the name of the product?
- Should I abandon this Google+ profile, and create a different new Google+ page for the product, from scratch, separate from the YouTube account? This forces me to also create a new YouTube account. Any other drawback doing this?
- Any better alternative?

Comment: I had this happen to me too. I had a Google Plus page that was not about me but about search engines, NO SEO though! I associated it with my YouTube account and a WordPress blog, no SEO tips! I also have a Google Plus profile, with a personal WordPress blog, my person-type tumblr blog and my Twitter account. All of those are mapped to my Gmail account, which is mapped to my Google Plus profile. About a month ago, Google seems to have tried to merge all of them, and I don't know what is going on now. I keep trying to separate everything, but it reverts back.

Comment: @FeralOink: I haven't risked myself to filling the last screenshot above, have you tried? Does it impact your YouTube name without ways to changing the YouTube name back?

Comment: I haven't received that prompt. I would be afraid to do it, as I think it might not be reversible. Several months ago, I recall getting a different prompt, asking if I wanted to associate my identity with one of my two YouTube accounts. I said yes, and now have two, according to Google, one with the user name in Camel Case, the other all lower case. Both have the same content, neither are mapped to my Google Page. I wouldn't enter anything in that form until someone gives you some guidance, here or on Google Product Forums. Here is a good start though!

Comment: Here is a good Google+ community for YouTube and Google+ integration problems: https://plus.google.com/communities/116715546192712015485 The experts hang out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two months after, no satisfying solution appeared, so I gave up and:

- Created a new Gmail address
- Used the Gmail address to create a new Google Plus page for the product
- Used the Gmail address to create a new YouTube account
- Created a new YouTube channel linked to the Google Plus page

Drawbacks:

- All of the past YouTube videos stay on the old account, lowering discoverability in both ways
- Likes/followers are split into 2 accounts
- Have to follow statistics for both the old and new accounts

*UPDATE 2015/07/28: Google has just announced that it will finally uncouple YouTube from Google+ so the procedure will probably become much easier.*